# Como desenvolver um carrossel que siga o mouse com translate3d

Tags: html, css, front-end, carousel

Gostaria de saber se vocês já haviam visto algum carrossel assim, ou se vocês tivessem que desenvolver um parecido como fariam? Preciso implementá-lo num site mas estou com dificuldade pra fazer a parte do movimento que  que ocorre no hover acompanhando o mouse e se tem algum nome específico pra esse efeito que eu possa estar procurando. Agradeço

[image: carrossel]

O link que peguei pra exemplo é https://www.ypiyachts.com/ está no final da página. Valeu galera

Comment: Tb não sei o nome desse efeito, mas não deve ser difícil fazê-lo. Basta pegar a posição X e Y do mouse e mover os elementos, talvez utilizando os eventos `mouseenter`, `mousemove` e `mouseleave`.

Comment: obrigado, irei tentar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O efeito que vocês está procurando chama `Tilt Hover Effect`, infelizmente eu nao consegui importar a biblioteca dele para de mostrar uma case funcional semelhante ao que vocês está mostrando no exemplo.

Aqui onde você pode encontrar mais exemplos: https://tympanus.net/Development/TiltHoverEffects/

Você terá que importar a biblioteca anime.js e a estrutura fica assim:

html

```
<a href="#" class="tilter tilter--2">
<figure class="tilter__figure">
    <img class="tilter__image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" alt="img03" />
    <div class="tilter__deco tilter__deco--shine"><div></div></div>
    <div class="tilter__deco tilter__deco--overlay"></div>
    <figcaption class="tilter__caption">
        <h3 class="tilter__title">Helen Portland</h3>
        <p class="tilter__description">Seattle</p>
    </figcaption>
    <svg class="tilter__deco tilter__deco--lines" viewBox="0 0 300 415">
        <path d="M20.5,20.5h260v375h-260V20.5z" />
    </svg>
</figure>
```

css

```
    .tilter {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    flex: none;
    width: 300px;
    height: 415px;
    margin: 1.5em 2.5em;
    color: #fff;
    perspective: 1000px;
}

.tilter * {
    pointer-events: none;
}

.tilter:hover,
.tilter:focus {
    color: #fff;
    outline: none;
}

.tilter__figure,
.tilter__image {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

.tilter__figure > * {
    transform: translateZ(0px); /* Force correct stacking order */
}

.tilter__figure {
    position: relative;
}

.tilter__figure::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 5%;
    left: 5%;
    width: 90%;
    height: 90%;
    box-shadow: 0 30px 20px rgba(35,32,39,0.5);
}

.tilter__deco {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.tilter__deco--overlay {
    background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(226, 60, 99, 0.4), rgba(145, 58, 252, 0.4), rgba(16, 11, 192, 0.4));
}

.tilter__deco--shine div {
    position: absolute;
    top: -50%;
    left: -50%;
    width: 200%;
    height: 200%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25) 50%, transparent 100%);
}

.tilter__deco--lines {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #fff;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.tilter__caption {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 4em;
}

.tilter__title {
    font-family: 'Abril Fatface', serif;
    font-size: 2.5em;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1;
    margin: 0;
}

.tilter__description {
    font-size: 0.85em;
    margin: 1em 0 0 0;
    letter-spacing: 0.15em;
}
```

js

```
Initialize:

new TiltFx(el, [options]);

The options:

var options = {
    movement: {
        // The main wrapper.
        imgWrapper : {
            translation : {x: 10, y: 10, z: 30},
            rotation : {x: 0, y: -10, z: 0},
            reverseAnimation : {duration : 200, easing : 'easeOutQuad'}
        },
        // The SVG lines element.
        lines : {
            translation : {x: 10, y: 10, z: [0,70]},
            rotation : {x: 0, y: 0, z: -2},
            reverseAnimation : {duration : 2000, easing : 'easeOutExpo'}
        },
        // The caption/text element.
        caption : {
            rotation : {x: 0, y: 0, z: 2},
            reverseAnimation : {duration : 200, easing : 'easeOutQuad'}
        },
        // The overlay element.
        overlay : {
            translation : {x: 10, y: -10, z: 0},
            rotation : {x: 0, y: 0, z: 2},
            reverseAnimation : {duration : 2000, easing : 'easeOutExpo'}
        },
        // The shine element.
        shine : {
            translation : {x: 100, y: 100, z: 0},
            reverseAnimation : {duration : 200, easing : 'easeOutQuad'}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Provavelmente conseguirei com isso mesmo, obrigado, irei tentar e aviso.